# How can I show a Popup or an Inject depending on the url on a Chrome Extension icon click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome Extension where I want a different action to happen depending on the URL where you click the extension icon.  On page type A, I want to have a standard dropdown popup, which I have created.  On page type B, I want to do a page injection without the popup being activated and have a div overlay on the actual page.

When I try to use the browseraction onclicked listener, nothing registers as I don't think you can use that if you have default_popup in your manifest.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is it possible? "Yes". Is the "normal" way of doing this, [`page_action`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), not sufficient for what you are wanting to do? Or [`chrome.browserAction.setPopup(object details)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup) based on the URL of the current tab.

Comment: @Makyen I am trying to do that, but where can I use setPopup?   Do I put that in a listener.

Comment: At first glance, [`tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) combined with specifying the `tabId` in the `details` object passed to `chrome.browserAction.setPopup(object details)` appears appropriate.